# Event Handler - Unauthorised access error

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, event-receivers, splistitem, event-handlers

So, on my ItemAdded receiver, I am looking to update a list item field. Now, if the user adding the item to the list, has sufficient permissions/privileges, this all runs smoothly. If not, the code will error on the `properties.ListItem.Update();` line. Not ideal.

Where my understanding falls down, is that I am running this update within a `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivleges` block. Code below;

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        try
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                properties.ListItem["Title"] = "Some Text"
                properties.ListItem.Update();
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
```

The error I'm currently getting is an "unauthorised access" error. The process seems to running under the credentials of the user rather than the System account (as I would expect of I were running with elevated privileges?)

Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you add more info about what is the error that you get after running this code?

Comment: Ahh thank you, apologies I omitted that actual error. Edited my post above

Comment: I haven't faced similar problems, but, if the code doesn't provide more info about the StackTrace of the error, I suggest you check this [page](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/logging-uls-sharepoint-2010/) and use the code provided there `SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace` for write in the SharePoint logs the error raised in the try/ catch block. After that, run again the code and check in the log files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in a [very recent answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/171392/35604),  any code running inside an elevated section must use new fresh SharePoint objects. This means you cannot use pre-created `SPListItem` or anything else generated from an `SPSite` not created under the elevated section.
Here, you use `properties.ListItem` that was created long before your elevation. This object is not considered elevated.

You thus have to recreate everything in the elevated section, something like:

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
   try
   {
      string webUrl = properties.WebUrl;
      Guid listId = properties.ListId;
      int itemId = properties.ListItemId;
      SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
      {
         using(SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(webUrl)
         {
            using(SPWeb elevatedWeb = elevatedSite.OpenWeb())
            {
               SPList elevatedList = elevatedWeb.Lists[listId];
               SPListItem elevatedItem = elevatedList.GetItemById(itemId);
               elevatedItem["Title"] = "Some Text"
               elevatedItem.SystemUpdate(); // SystemUpdate instead of Update to keep "Modified by" as is
            }
         }
      });
   }
   catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```